# T-test for groups within a Pandas dataframe for a unique id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, t-test

I have the following dataframe and I am performing a t-test between all days of the weekday and all days of a weekend in a month for every ID.

```
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | id  | usage_day  | dow       | tow     | daily_avg |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 01/09/2020 | Tuesday   | week    | 393.07    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 02/09/2020 | Wednesday | week    | 10.38     |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 03/09/2020 | Thursday  | week    | 429.35    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 04/09/2020 | Friday    | week    | 156.20    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 05/09/2020 | Saturday  | weekend | 346.22    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 06/09/2020 | Sunday    | weekend | 106.53    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 08/09/2020 | Tuesday   | week    | 194.74    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 10/09/2020 | Thursday  | week    | 66.30     |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 17/09/2020 | Thursday  | week    | 163.84    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 18/09/2020 | Friday    | week    | 261.81    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 19/09/2020 | Saturday  | weekend | 410.30    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 20/09/2020 | Sunday    | weekend | 266.28    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 23/09/2020 | Wednesday | week    | 346.18    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 24/09/2020 | Thursday  | week    | 20.67     |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 25/09/2020 | Friday    | week    | 222.23    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 26/09/2020 | Saturday  | weekend | 449.84    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 27/09/2020 | Sunday    | weekend | 438.47    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 28/09/2020 | Monday    | week    | 10.44     |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 29/09/2020 | Tuesday   | week    | 293.59    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+ | c96 | 30/09/2020 | Wednesday | week    | 194.49    |
> +-----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

My script is as follows, but it is unfortunately too slow and not the pandas way of doing things.
How I could do it more efficiently?

```
    from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, ttest_ind_from_stats

    p_val = []
    stat_flag = []
    all_ids = df.id.unique()
    alpha = 0.05
    print(len(all_ids))
    for id in all_ids:
        t = df[df.id ==  id]
        group1 = t[t.tow == 'week']
        group2 = t[t.tow == 'weekend']
        t, p_value_ttest = ttest_ind(group1.daily_avg, group2.daily_avg, equal_var=False)
        if p_value_ttest < alpha:
           p_val.append(p_value_ttest)
           stat_flag.append(1)
        else: 
           p_val.append(p_value_ttest)
           stat_flag.append(0)
```

p-val gives the p-values for every id.

Comment: Do not make screenshot, copy paste data instead. Picture are very poor medium for numerical data. Also read [mcve] to better understand why it is important to have a workable sample of input data.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I have replaced the image with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dataset

Based on dataset you provided:

```
import io
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd

s = """id|usage_day|dow|tow|daily_avg
c96|01/09/2020|Tuesday|week|393.07
c96|02/09/2020|Wednesday|week|10.38
c96|03/09/2020|Thursday|week|429.35
c96|04/09/2020|Friday|week|156.20
c96|05/09/2020|Saturday|weekend|346.22
c96|06/09/2020|Sunday|weekend|106.53
c96|08/09/2020|Tuesday|week|194.74
c96|10/09/2020|Thursday|week|66.30
c96|17/09/2020|Thursday|week|163.84
c96|18/09/2020|Friday|week|261.81
c96|19/09/2020|Saturday|weekend|410.30
c96|20/09/2020|Sunday|weekend|266.28
c96|23/09/2020|Wednesday|week|346.18
c96|24/09/2020|Thursday|week|20.67
c96|25/09/2020|Friday|week|222.23
c96|26/09/2020|Saturday|weekend|449.84
c96|27/09/2020|Sunday|weekend|438.47
c96|28/09/2020|Monday|week|10.44
c96|29/09/2020|Tuesday|week|293.59
c96|30/09/2020|Wednesday|week|194.49"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='|')
```

I add a new `id` with similar data for `groupby` clarity sake:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['id'] = 'c97'
df = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

#### MCVE

You do not have to resort to any explicit loop, instead **take advantage of the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method which operates on frames and also works with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)**.

To do that, we define a function performing the desired test on a DataFrame (`groupby` will call this method for each sub dataframe corresponding to combination of grouped keys):

```
def ttest(x):
    g = x.groupby('tow').agg({'daily_avg': list})
    r = stats.ttest_ind(g.loc['week', 'daily_avg'], g.loc['weekend', 'daily_avg'], equal_var=False)
    s = {k: getattr(r, k) for k in r._fields}
    return pd.Series(s)
```

Then it suffices to chain `apply` after the `groupby` call:

```
T = df.groupby('id').apply(ttest)
```

Results is about:

```
     statistic    pvalue
id                      
c96  -2.128753  0.059126
c97  -2.128753  0.059126
```

#### Refactoring

Once you have understood the power of this methodology, you can refactor the above code into a reusable function such as:

```
def ttest(x, y):
    return stats.ttest_ind(x, y, equal_var=False)

def apply_test(x, subgroup='tow', value='daily_avg', key1='week', key2='weekend', test=ttest):
    g = x.groupby(subgroup).agg({value: list})
    r = test(g.loc[key1, value], g.loc[key2, value])
    return pd.Series({k: getattr(r, k) for k in r._fields})

T = df.groupby('id').apply(apply_test, subgroup='anotherbucket', key1='experience', key2='reference', value='threshold')
```

Which allow you to adapt statistical tests and DataFrame columns with respect to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot benchmark without sample data, but maybe you could try a groupby instead of your for loop:

```py
for id,t in df.groupby('id'):    
    group1 = t[t.tow == 'week']
    group2 = t[t.tow == 'weekend']
    t, p_value_ttest = ttest_ind(group1.daily_avg, group2.daily_avg, equal_var=False)
    if p_value_ttest < alpha:
        p_val.append(p_value_ttest)
        stat_flag.append(1)
    else: 
        p_val.append(p_value_ttest)
        stat_flag.append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, It is definitely much faster now! I was wondering if I can perhaps apply a Lambda function with a t-test?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where to put a lambda function there, but for this particular case, I don't think you would gain performance that way.