# One-sided one sample T test by group on data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dplyr, scipy

I am trying to perform a one-sided, one sample T test by group on a pandas data frame in python. I feel like I am so close, but I just can't close the last bit. I was trying to follow something similar to these questions ([One Sided One Sample T Test Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947229/one-sided-one-sample-t-test-python) and [T-test for groups within a Pandas dataframe for a unique id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314956/t-test-for-groups-within-a-pandas-dataframe-for-a-unique-id)).

Say for example I have a data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                          'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                          'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'value': [0.200, 0.201, 0.189, 0.199, 0.205, 
                             0.220, 0.225, 0.209, 0.218, 0.230, 
                             0.308, 0.291, 0.340, 0.444, 0.275]})
```

and I wanted to generate a new data frame `df_pval` with just two columns: the 'ID' and p-value from a one-sided, one sample T test. I could do this in R like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df_pval <- df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     summarise(res = list(t.test(value, mu = 0.220, alternative = 'greater')))

df_pval <- data.frame(ID = df_pval$ID,
     pval = sapply(df_pval$res, function(x) x[['p.value']]))
```

In fact, right now I use `os` to run an external R script to perform this action, but I know it must be possible just in python. I have tried creating a 'groupby' object and then running `.apply`:

```
df_groupID = df.groupby('ID').agg({'value': list})
df_groupID.apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_1samp(x['value'], 0.220))
```

but this doesn't work. As of now I'm stuck. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance and sorry if this has already been answered before (and I just didn't understand the solution).

Comment: I don't know R (:/) so will you please show a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this (using `scipy-1.7.3`):

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                          'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                          'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'value': [0.200, 0.201, 0.189, 0.199, 0.205, 
                             0.220, 0.225, 0.209, 0.218, 0.230, 
                             0.308, 0.291, 0.340, 0.444, 0.275]})
df_groupID = df.groupby('ID').agg({'value': list})

df_groupID['value'] = df_groupID.value.apply(lambda x : stats.ttest_1samp(x, 0.220, alternative='greater').pvalue)
df_groupID = df_groupID.rename(index=str, columns={'value':'pval'})
```

```
        pval
ID          
A   0.999335
B   0.457619
C   0.010342
```

which is equivalent to:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
   ID = c ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                          'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                          'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
   value = c(0.200, 0.201, 0.189, 0.199, 0.205, 
                             0.220, 0.225, 0.209, 0.218, 0.230, 
                             0.308, 0.291, 0.340, 0.444, 0.275)
)

df_pval <- df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     summarise(res = list(t.test(value, mu = 0.220, alternative = 'greater')))
df_pval <- data.frame(ID = df_pval$ID,
     pval = sapply(df_pval$res, function(x) x[['p.value']]))
print(df_pval)
```

```
  ID       pval
1  A 0.99933491
2  B 0.45761885
3  C 0.01034185
```

Comment: For scipy 1.5 it gives error `TypeError: ttest_1samp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alternative'`

Comment: Yes, that is a really old version of scipy.. the `alternative` argument did not exist yet. You will have to update to a newer version.

Comment: Or just do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

For one-sided test, this should work for any version of scipy:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                          'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                          'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'value': [0.200, 0.201, 0.189, 0.199, 0.205, 
                             0.220, 0.225, 0.209, 0.218, 0.230, 
                             0.308, 0.291, 0.340, 0.444, 0.275]})


df.groupby('ID')['value'].apply(lambda x: stats.ttest_1samp(list(x),
                                popmean=0.220).pvalue/2) # divide by 2 for one-sided (alternative='greater' or 'smaller')
```

Gives:

```
ID
A    0.000665
B    0.457619
C    0.010342
```

Comment: This also works! Thank you.